# Entity Framework: Fluent API. How should I map this relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

My table is as follows:

```
create table Entities(
    EntityId bigint not null identity(1, 1),
    Name nvarchar(64) not null,
    ParentEntityId bigint null
)
alter table Entities add constraint PK primary key (EntityId)
alter table Entities add constraint FK foreign key (ParentEntityId) references Entities(EntityId)
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual long EntityId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual long? ParentEntityId { get; set; }

    public virtual Entity ParentEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to map the `ParentEntity` property with fluent api mapping, but I couldn't get this to work. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fixed code discrepancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fluent will work for you:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.ParentEntity)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentEntityId );
```

Created this database for me:

[image]